# Scatter plot in matplotlib not updating xlim and ylim

Tags: matplotlib

Given the below code I would expect the x-axis to be between 0 and 3 with some margins added.
Instead it is much larger. I would expect the call to scatter to automatically update x-axis limits.
I could set the xlim and ylim my self but would like them to be set automatically. What am I doing wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__':

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    x = [0, 4000, 8000, 100000]
    y = [0, 10, 100, 150]
    ax.scatter(x, y)

    x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    y = x

    ax.clear()

    ax.scatter(x, y)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clear the figure, and open a new subplot, than the axes will be adjusted as you wanted.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = [0, 4000, 8000, 100000]
y = [0, 10, 100, 150]
ax.scatter(x, y)

plt.clf()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
y = x

ax.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

**Edit:** In this version figure is not closed, just cleared with the clf function.

Comment: This is what I've ended up using, but it seems a waste to recreate figure each time a new scatter plot is needed.

Answer (score 2):

It is a feature that `scatter` does not automatically re-limit the graph as in many cases that would be undesirable.  See [`Axes.autoscale`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.autoscale) and [`Axes.relim`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.relim)

```
ax.relim()  # might not be needed 
ax.autoscale()
```

should do what you want.

Comment: I've tried both with and without running relim() without luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of making another scatter plot without needing to clear the figure.
I basically update offests of PathCollection returned by axes.scatter() and add the collection back to the axes. Of course, the axes has to be cleared first. One thing I notice is that I have to manually set the margins.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = [0, 4000, 8000, 100000]
y = [0, 10, 100, 150]
scat = ax.scatter(x, y)

x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
y = x

ax.clear()
corners = (min(x), min(y)), (max(x), max(y))
ax.update_datalim(corners)
ax.margins(0.05, 0.05)
ax.autoscale_view()
scat.set_offsets(np.vstack((x,y)).transpose())
ax.add_collection(scat)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you comment out the first scatter, everything will be fine

Comment: Sure, but why does it not work with the first scatter as is? This is just a simple example, but I have the same issue in a more complex application I am writing.